# My 2005 mazda 3 has power sometimes, runs great, then another ill start it and it has no power it just doesnt wanna go. Gas to the floor and all

Tags: troubleshooting, mazda, mazda-3, intermittent-problems

[image]

I've changed spark plugs, coil packs, cleaned the body with 2+2, codes of thermostat and aor mass flow sensor came up. Car is not overheating. Runs fine then sometimes when started has no power to go, keep restarting it and does same thing, runs great all day sometimes then just suddenly has no power. Please help!!?

Comment: When it happens, does your PRNDL light go out? This happened to me once and it was the ignition switch. And the PRNDL light going out when it randomly happened was the indicator.

Comment: Post the OBD codes please.

Answer (score 1):

Check the electrical connection and grounding of your mass airflow meter. If the electrical connection is loose or corroded, the computer will get the incorrect information about how much air is getting into the engine and will be adding the incorrect amount of fuel, making the car not go very well.

Keep in mind, the mass airflow sensor could also be defective. These are expensive, so you may want to swap it for one from the junkyard just to see if it makes a difference.